# Update mysql in if condition in php

Tags: php, mysql, post, sql-update

I have a problem. In `visual_form_builder` (wordpress plugin) that I would like to post fields value and after with these field values I'd like to update record in my mysql table.

The problem is that if there is no condition, just `mysql_query` command then command run, and it update `field_description` field in mysql table.

But it is in IF condition, it does not update mysql table, but it displays "post". If I put insert command into mysql query, then it runs and insert new line to dbtable.

Any ideas? Please help me and Thanks in advance!

Here is my php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['save_form']))
{
    print "post<br>";
    mysql_query("UPDATE wp_visual_form_builder_fields SET field_description='value4' WHERE field_id = '31'");            
}
```

Here is part of html code of source code:

```
<form method="post" id="visual-form-builder-update" action="">
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="update_form" />
<input name="form_id" type="hidden" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="2cc2423188" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=visual-form-builder&amp;form=3" />
<div id="form-editor-header">
    <div id="submitpost" class="submitbox">
        <div class="vfb-major-publishing-actions">
            <label for="form-name" class="menu-name-label howto open-label">
                <span class="sender-labels">Űrlap neve</span>
                <input type="text" value="R-ma-6001" placeholder="Adja meg az űrlap neve itt" class="menu-name regular-text menu-item-textbox required" id="form-name" name="form_title" />
            </label>

            <br class="clear" />

            <div class="vfb-button-group">
                <a href="#form-settings" id="form-settings-button" class="vfb-button vfb-settings ">
                    Beállítások                     <span class="vfb-interface-icon vfb-interface-settings"></span>
                </a>

                <a href="http://www......./wp-admin/admin.php?page=visual-form-builder&#038;action=copy_form&#038;form=3&#038;_wpnonce=4529497ba1" class="vfb-button vfb-duplicate">
                    Duplicate                       <span class="vfb-interface-icon vfb-interface-duplicate"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="http://www.........../wp-admin/admin.php?page=visual-form-builder&#038;action=delete_form&#038;form=3&#038;_wpnonce=79a27ab860" class="vfb-button vfb-delete vfb-last menu-delete">
                    Törlés                      <span class="vfb-interface-icon vfb-interface-trash"></span>
                </a>

                <input type="submit" name="save_form" id="save_form" class="button button-primary" value="Save"  />
            </div>

            <!-- truncated -->
```

Comment: Consider rephrasing. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Well...what do you think wheather my php code is correct?

Comment: This updating query should run if I click Save button. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of `field_id`? `Varchar` or `int`?

You can test it by capturing the request send to the mysql server if you have enough privilege.

But as you mentioned `INSERT` worked, I'd guess its a statement related.

run:

```
show create table tablename;
```

To get your table schema.

Comment: type of field_id is BIGINT

Comment: I ran this Show create table mytablename...but I always use this setup, in other cases it works. Do you think Visual Form Builder has a special setup what is not allowed to update with $_POST?

Comment: I'm not familier with the visual form builder. Normally it should grant you select\insert\update\drop privilege to the user which your php code used to connect to db. You can double check it by:

Comment: If it's privilege issue, You can double check it by:   Select * from mysql.user\G; and select * from mysql.db\G;   . That's mysql instance and db level privilege. data type looks fine. Does the update statement worke when you manully run it?